# Recover deleted files from encrypted drive

Tags: 16.04, encryption, data-recovery, photorec

I was organising pictures when I accidentally deleted a big part of my good pictures along with the thrash pictures.

So I instantly stopped all file transferring actions and ran photorec (would have probably been better to first shut off the computer and run it from a live usb, but that is not what I've done). Now I have a ton of folders and files on an external hdd that are some kind of `number.eCryptfs`

My question would be how i could decrypt those files.
I run Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How were they encrypted in the first place?

Comment: from default with the installation

Comment: Reiterating what @George has already asked and clarifying, did you actually create an encrypted disk partition (LUKS) or did you simply encrypt your home directory (ecryptfs which is not the same as an encrypted drive)? Both are available options during install. From your description in your question, it's sounding like you're talking about home directory encryption.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was not clear. It is indeed home directory encryption.